# PDF generation: Can Data be filtered?

Tags: orbeon

We are evaluating Orbeon for a very large form with multiple pages of PDF output. In order to streamline the output, we would like to generate a template-based PDF composed of sections of text dependent on how the user responds to a question. Can this sort of PDF be generated?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you referring to a zone with text, where you'd like have answers to questions inserted at specific positions? E.g. a message saying "Thank you John for filling out this form", where "John" comes with the value of the field "First name".

Comment: No, say the form question is: What is in the soup? And responses are The soup contains water, The soup contains meat, The soup contains oats. The respondent checks the "meat" answer. Then text associated with that answer (and that answer only) is inserted into the pdf output. Then, on to the next question which would be handled the same way.

Comment: To add to that, you had it partly correct. Say the respondent's name is John. Then the output would read: John uses meat in his soup. So in this instance, there are two pieces being inserted into the output, "John" and a sentence about "meat".

Comment: Another clarification: do you mean that you want to use a PDF template, as  in the ["PDF templates" feature](http://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/pdf-templates.html), correct?

Comment: @ggatlanta OK, so let's try this: generally, you would add an output field with a calculated value using the following expression: `concat($first-name, ' uses ', $ingredient, ' in his soup')`. Assuming the value of the field `first-name` is "John" and the value of the `ingredient` field is "meat", this will output "John uses meat in his soup".

Comment: @ggatlanta Note that, so far, this is irrelevant of the PDF generation, i.e. the output field will show both in the form and the PDF. Were you also saying that you'd like that value to only show in the PDF?